# Trying to pass value/variable/params to url and new window

Tags: javascript, variables, parameters, new-window

I'm trying to pass some values to a new window URL:

```
   function sendInfo() {
        
    
        var params = new URLSearchParams();
         params.append("ozip", publicOzip);
         params.append("dzip", publicDzip);
         params.append("ocity",ocitystatetext);
         params.append("dcity", dcitystatetext);
        
        var url = "/critracker.html?" + params.toString();
        location.href = "/critracker.html?";
        
    }
```

however i am getting a "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'var' "  on the second window which contains the code:

```
    function get () 
    { 
      var params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search), 
      var   ozip = params.get("ozip"); 
      var   dzip = params.get("dzip");
      var   ocity = params.get("ocity");
      var   dcity = params.get("dcity"); 
}
```

The new window does not open with the variables as parameters , does anyone have any tips for sending variables and their values to a new window?

Answer (score 0):

```
var params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search),
```

You have a comma at the end of the line here. Delete the comma and it will be fine.